# How do I customize the window bar color in Windows 10 when high contrast mode is active?

Tags: windows-10, colors, desktop-customization, themes, accessibility

I have high contrast mode turned on in Windows 10. But I don't like the blue and purple window bar color. How can I change it? Is it possible by editing the registry or what?

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Thanks!